# Python filter defaultdict

Tags: python, filter, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict of lists, but I want to basically do this:

```
myDefaultDict = filter(lambda k: len(k)>1, myDefaultDict)
```

Except it only seems to work with lists. What can I do?

Comment: Do you want to remove items that have a key longer than 1 or a value longer than 1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying to get only values with len > 1?

Dictionary comprehensions are a good way to handle this:

```
reduced_d = {k: v for k, v in myDefaultDict.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

As martineau pointed out, this does not give you the same `defaultdict` functionality of the source `myDefaultDict`.  You can use the dict comprehension on defaultdict instantiaion, as martineau shows to get the same `defaultdict` functionality.

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDefaultDict = defaultdict(list, {'ab': [1,2,3], 'c': [4], 'def': [5,6]})  # original 
reduced_d = defaultdict(list, {k: v for k, v in myDefaultDict.items() if len(v) > 1})
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. Is the .items() needed?

Comment: yes `.items()` converts it into a list of tuples containing the key value pairs

Comment: There's no need to do the `orig_d = myDefaultDict` — it accomplishes nothing useful, and just creates another name for the `myDefaultDict` object. Also note that the `reduced_d` object created is not a `defaultdict` like the original, it's just a plain dictionary.

Comment: @martineau thanks, your right, I removed `orig_d` for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you want to delete keys or values longer than 1.

Assuming it's the length of the key, here's how to do it with filter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# create test data
my_defaultdict = defaultdict(list, {'ab': [1,2,3], 'c': [4], 'def': [5,6]})

my_defaultdict = defaultdict(my_defaultdict.default_factory,
                             filter(lambda i: len(i[0])>1, my_defaultdict.items()))

print(my_defaultdict)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'ab': [1, 2, 3], 'def': [5, 6]})
```

If it's the length of the associated value, just change the `len(i[0])` to `len(i[1])`.

Comment: Cool use of a `lambda` in default dict

Comment: dawg: Thanks, though a dictionary comprehension is equally viable way of accomplishing this.The main purpose of my post was to demonstrate how `filter()` could be adapted to work with something other than a list (a dictionary or `defaultdict` in this case).

Comment: FWIW, I ran some timing tests, and using a dictionary comprehension was faster than using `filter()` the way I've shown, However @dwag's answer was even faster than that (by about 10% using Python 2). However, a Python 3 compatible version of dwag's was the slowest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter and then use `map` to remove each dict entry based on the filtered condition:

```
>>> example={'l1':[1], 'l2':[2,3], 'l3':[4,5,6], 'l4':[7]}
>>> filter(lambda k: len(example[k])<2, example)
['l4', 'l1']
>>> map(example.__delitem__, filter(lambda k: len(example[k])<2, example))
[None, None]
>>> example
{'l2': [2, 3], 'l3': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: Using `filter()` to get the keys to delete is clever. However using `map()` just for its side-effects is often frowned-upon. Another possible disadvantage is using `map()` by itself this way won't work in Python 3 (and the fix is calling another function also strictly for its side-effects).